# Exim router to catch local emails

Tags: email, exim, router, amazon-ses

I'm trying to setup Exim with Amazon's SES. I've defined a router that catches **all** emails and sends them through SES. I don't want to filter anything for outboud. Everything goes through SES. My router config is the following:

```
begin routers

aws_ses:
  debug_print = "R: aws_ses for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = accept
  require_files = AWS_SES_SEND_EMAIL : AWS_CREDENTIALS_FILE
  transport = aws_ses_pipe
  no_more
```

It's working great except for one problem. Whenever I get any **inbound** email, Exim also tries sending them through SES. That's the problem. Local emails should be caught by Exim. I tried adding this just *before* my aws_ses router but it's not working. Exim still uses the aws_ses router for inbound emails to mydomain.com

```
localusers:
  driver = accept
  domains = mylocaldomain.com
  transport = virtual_userdelivery
```

So, how do I make Exim send all outbound emails through aws_ses router but at the same time, tell it to catch all inbound mails to mydomain.com so that it can be delivered to the user's mailboxes?

Thanks.

p.s. You can see the complete configuration on the [tutorial](http://www.csrdu.org/nauman/2011/08/12/setting-up-exim-to-use-amazon-simple-email-service-ses/) I've put together. The relevant configs are pasted in this question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routers are tried in order.  You should just have been able to find a Router named "dnslookup" or "smarthost" or somesuch, and put your new router there in its place.  Completely replacing the list of Routers is not advisable unless you have a lot of Exim experience (and the same goes for the RCPT ACL).

You should have a domainlist called `local_domains`, which is a list of domains to be handled on this host itself.  Then, your `aws_ses` Router would include a line:

```
domains = !+local_domains
```

With that pre-condition in place, mails sent to a domain in the `local_domains` domainlist will not be handled by the `aws_ses` Router.

Next: you talk about `mydomain.com` in the text but then use `mylocaldomain.com` in your obfuscated example.  An error like that would certainly explain what you're seeing.  :)

Then: use something like:

```
$ exim -d -bt fred@mydomain.com
```

to get some copious debugging output about the decisions Exim is making in deciding how to handle that address.

Comment: Hehe, thanks for pointing out the 'local' mistake. That crept in during the obfuscation. Didn't want to look like I was promoting a client's website or anything. Your solution works though.